# How to embed a PNG with transparent background in AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad

I would like to add a logo to AutoCAD. This logo is a PNG with transparent background.

If I attached the file, it keeps the transparent background, but I need to keep the png file because it is an external reference.

The other option is to paste the image from paint, the steps are:

1.- Open the png in paint, select all and copy.
2.- In AutoCAD, insert OLE object and choose the paintbrush object. This opens a new window of paint.
3.- I select all in and in the select tool I select a transparent background.
4.- It removes the background in paint, but when it is inserted in AutoCAD, it still keeps the white background.

So I don't know how to embed a PNG file with transparent background in AutoCAD.

How could I do it?

I am using Autocad 2021.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to have the image displayed transparent globally put it on a layer and set this layer's property "Transparency" to a value > 0 and make sure that

    sysvar TRANSPARENCY is on for the display
 and    in the plot dialog the checkbox for "Plot transparency" is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you import the PNG, click on it to select it and then go to your Properties palette and change the "Background Transparency" setting to "Yes".

Taken from: https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/profile/1114-cad64/

An additional step would be to set the object's colour to 255,255,255 so it does not print the border and the line weight to 0.00mm also so it minimises the pure white.